# compiling vim on msys2 with python support

Tags: python, vim, compilation, msys2

Just wasted 5 hours so might as well ask here.

I am able to compile vim without problem (64bit system) :

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-tlib=ncursesw --enable-luainterp \
--with-lua-prefix=/usr/local --disable-gui --disable-tclinterp \
--enable-cscope --without-x CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I/usr/include/ncursesw" \
--enable-python3interp=dynamic --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic \
--enable-multibyte && make
```

The flags python/dyn and python3/dyn are both active

However, as soon as I try to execute python command from within the vim:

```
E370: Could not load library
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

To make things even more confusing, the native vim bundled with msys2 has working python support. After switching directories I discovered it uses

- /bin/msys-python2.7.dll
- /bin/msys-python3.3m.dll.

I tried to copy those files to different directories and change names to python27.dll or python2.7.dll. To no avail.

Comment: When running configure add `--enable-fail-if-missing` to make sure the configure script actually finds the python interpreters.

Comment: It does find them - I checked logs. The flag doesn't cause it to fail, unfortunately.

Comment: You're missing `--with-python-config-dir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vim executable was lingering in /usr/local/bin/ and corrupting the path.